# MVC 5 Strongly typed Numeric field min max is not properly working

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, max, min, numeric, strong-typing

my view has two text boxes 
 one is strongly typed and the other one is just a normal input field

```cs
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[index].Response, new { @type = "Number", @min = questionary.SurveyQuestion.Question.RateMin, @max = questionary.SurveyQuestion.Question.RateMax })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(p => Model[index].Response)
@Html.Raw("<input type='number' name='name' min='"+questionary.SurveyQuestion.Question.RateMin +"' max='" + questionary.SurveyQuestion.Question.RateMax + "' value='' />")
```

the view looks like this
[View screenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZmZ6d.png)

but validation does not work for strongly typed text box.
ex: if i enter 9 it will throw a validation error as below
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSTbC.png)

but the box should be able to enter number between 8 to 10

So can anyone please help me on this issue. Thank you very much.

Comment: What validation atribute do you have on the property (the `min` and `max` attributes have nothing to do the the validation message generate by `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`

Comment: There is also something odd about the html in the screenshot - it should have some `data-val` attributes - are you sure that's the correct code?

Comment: yes Stephen it does have that data-val property (not in the screenshot , but it appears when the validation hits)

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding. Your html should have a number of `data-val` attributes when the html is generated - at least `data-val="true" data-val-required="..." data-val-number="..."` etc. You need to show more of your view code, in particular the `for` loop your generating this in and the model  - showing the `Response` property and its attributes

Comment: ohh i got u.. yeah u r correct i don't get those to my html

Answer (score 0):

@Html.ValidationMessageFor() will work for if you have added DataAnnotation attribute for the same.

Set validation attribute on Response property as

```
Range[minVal,maxVal]
public int Response{get;set;}
```

Or if you want to add validation rule dynamically, you can use remote validation: here is an example
http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/669824/Implementing-Remote-Validation-in-MVC